# Using kinect in windows iot core

Tags: kinect, windows-10-iot-core

I want to use kinect 1.7 in windows iot but os doesn't have the driver. 
I want to id even it's possible to use kinect in windows iot and where to find the proper driver.
I'm using raspberry pi 2 the latest version of win iot but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

apparently, It's not possible to use  Kinect in Raspberry pi with windows IOT.
first, there is no proper driver for windows IOT version.
Second, The Kinect wouldn’t be integrated with the GPU though, unless MS and the Foundation hardware engineers create a Camera Serial Interface for the Kinect, and I don’t ever “see” that happening. The Pi USB bus is too slow to handle Kinect video from its camera, let alone the depth sensor and multi-array microphone data.
[Reference](https://www.raspberrypi.org/blog/windows-10-for-iot/)